# Upgrade to 22.04 stopped at Memtest86+

Tags: upgrade

I started the update from 22.04 to 22.04 last night and saw this morning that the upgrade stopped with the line "memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting". Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that line is normal on an UEFI system when grub installs the bootloader. Have you tried rebooting the system to see if actually works?

Comment: Yes.  It failed.  So I went ahead and reinstalled Ubuntu.  Thank you though.